# Comparisons in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, logical-operators

I am really confused in understanding this. I presume, I can write a return code comparison as give below.  Which is better? Why should it be?

```
RC=$?

if [[ $RC == '0' ]]; then
if [ $RC -eq '0' ]; then
if [ $RC == '0' ]; then
if [ "$RC" == "0" ]; then
if [ "$RC" -eq "0" ]; then
if [[ "$RC" == "0" ]]; then
if (( "$RC" == "0" )); then
if ( "$RC" == "0" ); then
if (( $RC == 0 )); then
if ( $RC == 0 ); then
```

And some more...

What if `RC="A"` -- String?

Comment: search for stirng & number comparison in unix and comparison of both using c syntax in unix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above.  In the vast majority of cases, you want to examine the exit code directly from within `if`.  Any code which looks like

```
command
RC=$?
if [ $RC == 0 ]; then
```

is much more elegantly, robustly, and idiomatically written

```
if command; then
```

unless you specifically need to examine the precise nonzero value of the result code.

To separately address your question about which comparison operator to use, the only fully portable variant is `[` with `=`.  The syntax of this legacy Bourne shell operator does not portably support `==` for equality, so that's wrong (though some shells allow it as a syntactic safety net).  The `-eq` operator compares for numeric equality, while `=` performs string comparison.

In modern shells, `[[` and `((` are both viable, depending on whether you care more about string comparisons (which is where `[[` makes sense) or arithmetic (which is the domain of `((` -- especially useful if the comparison involves some actual calculations on the numbers; but it is definitely the more fringe alternative, as it is not useful at all for string comparisons).  `[[` also supports pattern matching, so you are not confined to static string comparisons; unlike `[`, it requires a double equals sign for the string equality comparison.  It works around a number of thorny issues with `[`, included but not limited to correct behavior with unquoted variables and arguments which begin with a dash.

The alternative with a single parenthesis does not do at all what you want.  It attempts to run `$RC` as a command in a subshell.

Comment: Upvoted - thanks for your efforts. What if it is a string?

Comment: The returnvalue of a command `$?` never is a string. You could use `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` for these cases. Another possibility is skipping the keyword `if`, but I prefer to use that in few cases only: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194926/57293

Answer (score 1):

If you are in `Bash` it does not segregate its variables by *type*, but ... a `return` `code` is a numeric value, so i will bet in:

```
rc=$?

if (( ! rc )); then
  # rc == 0
  Do something
fi
```

Reason: maintain coherence in relation with the expected `type`.

Check: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html

Comment: Can you explain me why you bet on (( ))? Any advantages?

Comment: personal taste @realspirituals , explained in answer

Comment: Updated the questions. Thanks for the efforts so far